# CONTACT_ID - Keeping it in sync

Tags: android, contacts

I am interested in your opinions on the best way to keep a robust reference to a contact starting android 2.0. I have read a lot regarding this issue but i don't know which technique is advisable and if there's any new ones. Below are the 3 options i found so far:

1- Don't use your own db. Extend the contacts.contract to write your data

2 - Use ContentObserver to keep track of any changes made to the contacts. This technique would however require your application to be running

3- Store all RAW contact IDs related to a CONTACT_ID in your db and infer the content of the aggregate contact from all its constituent RAW contacts

In my case i need to keep a separate db and i was wondering if there's any other new technique of keeping the CONTACT_ID current after aggregations and dis-aggregations...

Please advise

Comment: I dint get your exact requirnment esp the 3rd point. Why is the need to store all RAW contact IDs in an application database as they can be extracted from the RAW_CONTACTS at any instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am playing with the new Contacts API at the moment, writing an app which is also a source of contact data. I can't recommend #3 at all. To get all of "my" contact data I simply store them with a magic value in the RawContacts.SYNC1 field and query the contacts content provider for that when my app starts up.

Re. your question, don't use CONTACT_IDs, as they are volatile. Use the lookup API, i.e. if you have a raw contact ID, use [RawContacts.getContactLookupUri()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html#getContactLookupUri%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri%29) to get to the Contact. Likewise if some API gives you a  contact ID, use [Contacts.getLookupUri()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#getLookupUri%28long,%20java.lang.String%29) to get a persistent identifier you can use later on.

Comment: Hi Reuben. My problem is that i am not implementing a sync adapter. I am just storing some contacts in my sql db and i need a robust reference to those contacts. To my understanding both lookup_key and contact_id change and i can't use any to match contacts.

Comment: Those APIs are not exclusively for SyncAdapters, and lookup URIs are valid for the lifetime of the contact. (But of course you still have to code for the case that contacts you're tracking can be deleted while your app isn't running).